# Sql query with mixed selected rows order

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I have a table that looks like below:

```
| id | group_id | title |
-------------------------
| 1  | 1        | Hello |
| 2  | 1        | World |
| 3  | 2        | Foo   |
| 4  | 2        | Bar   |
```

My query may look like below to return the results above:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY id
```

### Question

How can I order this table so that the group ids appears to be random, but still the same every time the query is executed.

#### Possible result example

This result looks to be in a random order. If I run the same query a week later, I want to see the exact same order which means it's not really random.

```
| id | group_id | title |
-------------------------
| 2  | 1        | World |
| 4  | 2        | Bar   |
| 1  | 1        | Hello |
| 3  | 2        | Foo   |
```

- Appears to be random from a group_id perspective. It's no longer ordered by `group_id` like 1 1 2 2, but 1 2 1 2. It could also have been 2 1 1 2 or something that does not increase.
- Should return the same results every time, not random each time.
- I could order by title but if a `title` should change that row will be reordered. So the order needs to be made with the `id` I guess.
- I want to avoid file or database caching if possible.

Is it possible?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also explain what you mean "random from a group_id" perspective.

Comment: What's with new records, are they allowed to pop up between the old?

Comment: Forget the question, 4 is new in respect to 1, so yes!

Answer (score 0):

How about taking the modulo function for your advantage.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY id % 3,id
```

Define a value to use with the modulo function (in my example 3) and order your table by the modulo of the id.
This should return the same order everytime you run the query and return some order that is pseudo random.

Since the modulo function can return the same value for different ids you also need to order by the original id to have a defined, reproducable order.

Comment: It did not work as good as I had hoped. It seems to kind of group blocks of rows together in a squence.

Comment: I solved it thanks to your inspiring answer. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> order this table so that the group ids appears to be random

Only `ORDER BY RAND()` may provide really random ordering.

> but still the same every time the query is executed

Create separate static ordering table, fill it randomly with source table's `id`s, join it and order by it.

Answer (score 0):

I did not solve the problem with the solution from @Kylro, but I found another way which works great.

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY COS(id), id
```

Cos is sometimes a positive value and sometimes a negative value, almost random like. It works perfecty for this problem.